# Sound output isn't working on my Intel NUC10i5FNK

Tags: 20.04, lts, soundcard, intel-nuc

I'm using this Intel [NUC10i5FNK](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/boards-kits/nuc/kits/nuc10i5fnk.html) (released in Q4'19) with a Creative GigaWorks T20 Speaker Series 1, which are indeed working (checked them on another NUC from a former generation running the same Ubuntu 20.04 LTS).

The sound over bluetooth by using earphones however does work.

I'm using the line-in box in front of the nuc as with the other nuc I tested them today.

In the settings/audio there is only "dummy" for output. What could cause the issue?

From some inputs from Hex-Chat the issue seems to be that Ubuntus Kernel of LTS 20.04 has some problems in addressing the hardware.

I finally found this thread:

https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-NUCs/NUC10i5-headphones-jack-audio-not-working-with-Ubuntu-20-04/td-p/643946

Comment: It's a bit of a pity that the system doesn't work with ubuntu yet.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the link.

Even if nuc isn't dell this works for me, add "options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi" to "/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf"